# Image File Compression before download into path using Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, image-compression

I am Downloading Image from Gmail, what the problem here is , Image file upto 6MB, So it will take some more time in order to complete its download process. So my Question is **Shall i compress image while downloading(ie Before save into path)?** I have looked some Image compression examples in java,but all are taking image from one path then compress and finally stores that compressed image into some other folder. 
If you want code for download attachment from gmail, Please click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117780/email-attachment-download-by-passing-email-message-id-using-imap?noredirect=1#comment102637294_58117780) . Could you please help me out to find the solution?

`````
/*Downloading EmailAttachment into localfolder*/
    public void downloadEmailAttachments(String protocol, String host, String port, String userName, String password,
            String tempDirectory,String saveDirectory,String MessageID,String HeaderID,String emailDate,String emailSubject, MessageContext context) {
   logger.info("===Inside downloadEmailAttachments Process====");
        Properties properties = getServerProperties(protocol, host, port);
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        int status = 0;
        try {
            Store store = session.getStore(protocol);
            store.connect(userName, password);
            Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            logger.info("No of Unread Messages : " + folderInbox.getUnreadMessageCount());
            /* create a search term for all "unseen" messages*/
            Flags seen = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
            FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen, false);


            SearchTerm searchTerm = new AndTerm(new MessageIDTerm(HeaderID), new SubjectTerm(emailSubject));
            Message[] arrayMessages = folderInbox.search(searchTerm);
            if(arrayMessages != null && arrayMessages.length > 0){

                Message message = arrayMessages[0];
                Address[] fromAddress = message.getFrom();

                String msgId=mimeMessage.getMessageID();*/
                String from = fromAddress[0].toString();

                String subject = message.getSubject();
                String sentDate = message.getSentDate().toString();

                String contentType = message.getContentType();


                String messageContent = "";
                String modifiedsubject=subject.toUpperCase().replaceAll("\\s+", "");

                String attachmentname = "";


                if(modifiedsubject.contains("SELLMYCAR")){  
                if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                    // content may contain attachments
                    Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                    int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                    for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                        MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                        if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                            // this part is attachment
                            //String fileName = part.getFileName();
                            // part.setFileName(ESBMessageID+":"+new Date());
                            // String fileName = part.getFileName()+":"+ESBMessageID+":"+new Date();
                            String fileName = part.getFileName();
                            fileName=fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(".")).concat(".jpg");
                            System.out.println("Modified FileName:" + fileName);
                            attachmentname = fileName;
                            /*part.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);*/
                            part.saveFile(tempDirectory + File.separator + fileName);

                            logger.info("Files are downloaded into "+ tempDirectory+" successfully");

                            if (attachmentname.length() > 1) {

                                attachmentname = attachmentname.substring(0, attachmentname.length());
                            }

                            /*FileMove Process*/
                            moveFile(tempDirectory,fileName,saveDirectory,MessageID,context);

                        } else {
                            // this part may be the message content
                            messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
                        }
                    }

                    // print out details of each message
                    logger.info("Message # :");
                    logger.info("\t From: " + from);
                    //logger.info("\t UserName: " + name);
                    logger.info("\t Subject: " + subject);
                    logger.info("\t Sent Date: " + sentDate);
                    //logger.info("\t UserMailID: " + email);
                    logger.info("\t Attachments: " + attachmentname);
                    logger.info("\t LocalDownloadpath: " + saveDirectory);



                } else if (contentType.contains("text/plain") || contentType.contains("text/html")) {
                    Object content = message.getContent();
                    if (content != null) {
                        messageContent = content.toString();
                    }
                }






            }
            }

            // disconnect
            folderInbox.close(false);
            store.close();
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {

            logger.info("Could not connect to the message store");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }````
`````

Comment: The issue with your idea is simple; in order to compress the image you must first download the image. Thus negating any advantage to performing the compression for the purposes of speeding up the download.

Comment: How long does it take to download 6 MB on a fast, modern network? Perhaps your code is sub-optimal? Care to share? Post your code so we can help you with it. By the way, I think your question is an example of the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: **Let me elaborate it:** I am working with WSO2 ESB with this class, what ESB did  is, it'll continuously access gmail for every 60 sec, and push the email content into Salesforce. This class is called before that SF Call. so before complete this class job, it will push same email content to SF at least 4 times. but the same class is works fine for size of KB images, when it comes to MB size, this will take some more time to download. So that i guess like to compress image size while downloading, so that it will not take more time to download. Let me know if anything is wrong?

Comment: If you control both the server and the client side of the download, conceivably you could compress it on the server and decompress it on the client.  But if you're dealing with an image format that's already compressed, that's not likely to help very much.